# Flutter signed app build Execution failed for task ':app:validateSigningRelease'

Tags: flutter

I am trying to build the signed app bundle
I have created the key and store in the path C:\Users\TRICON\key.jks

my key.properties file

```
storePassword=********
keyPassword=*******
keyAlias=key
storeFile=C:\Users\TRICON\key.jks
```

when i run flutter appbundle
i get the following error
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:validateSigningRelease'.

  > Keystore file 'C:\Users\TRICON\AndroidStudioProjects\taskmanager\android\app\C:UsersTRICONkey.jks' not found for signing config 'release'.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Any help on where am i going wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add you key.jks file in app folder of android and storeFile = key.jks

Answer (score 0):

Probably the issue is with your path. Probably you want represent the path with escape sequence to make it work.

```
storeFile=C:\\Users\\TRICON\\key.jks
```